# How to I populate a textarea with the contents within my div, containing a mixture of text and dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a section of my website with a madlib-style paragraph, requiring the user to select different inline dropdown options that complete the paragraph.

my HTML

```
<div id="aspirate">
BONE MARROW ASPIRATE AND TOUCH PREPARATION: The aspirate smears contain 
    <select name=asp_1>
        <option> few </option>
        <option> adequate </option>
        <option> numerous </option>
    </select>
    <select name=asp_2>
        <option> cellular </option>
        <option> paucicellular </option>
        <option> acellular </option>
    </select>
    marrow particles. Myeloid precursors appear 
<select name=asp_3>
        <option> adequate </option>
        <option> decreased </option>
        <option> increased </option>
    </select>    
in number with
    <select name=asp_4>
        <option> full-spectrum maturation </option>
        <option> left-shifted maturation </option>
    </select>. Erythroid precursors appear 
    <select name=asp_5>
        <option> adequate </option>
        <option> decreased </option>
        <option> increased </option>
    </select> in number with full-spectrum maturation <select name=asp_6>
        <option> and mild megaloblastic changes </option>
        <option> and mild dyspoies characterized by nuclear membrane irregularities and increased mitoses </option>
        <option> and occasional binucleate forms </option>
    </select>. 
    Megakaryocytes are 
    <select name=asp_7>
        <option> adequate </option>
        <option> decreased </option>
        <option> increased </option>
    </select> in number and normal in morphology. No dysplastic changes or increased numbers of blast cells are identified. No lymphoid infiltrates are identified. 
    <select name=asp_9>
        <option> </option>
        <option> The direct smears and touch preparation slides show similar cellular composition. </option>
        <option> The direct smear slides show similar cellular composition.</option>
    </select>  The iron stain shows 
    <select name=asp_10>
        <option> </option>
        <option> no ring sideroblasts, and </option>
        <option> rare ring sideroblasts, and </option>
    </select>
    <select name=asp_11>
        <option> adequate storage iron</option>
        <option> decreased storage iron </option>
        <option> increased storage iron </option>
    </select>.
</div>

<br>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onClick='document.getElementById("outPut4").innerHTML=document.getElementById("aspirate").innerText'>
<br>
<form>
<textarea id="outPut4" rows = 20 cols = 45></textarea>
</form>
```

This only returns the text minus the dropdown selections? Can this be done using just HTML or should I assign a variable value to each dropdown and use javascript to call a function that will write my text within the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it requires a JavaScript function that does the following:

1. Traverse each child node of the div.
2. Determine whether each is a text node or a select box.
3. Extract the value from each node.
4. Insert the combined values into the textarea.

Sample JavaScript:

```
function showText() {
    var html = '';
    // Get the first child node
    var dom = document.getElementById('aspirate').firstChild;
    while (dom) {
        if (dom.nodeType == 3) { // Text node
            html += dom.nodeValue; // Add the value
        }
        else if (dom.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'select') { // Select box
            html += dom.value; // Add the selected value
        }
        dom = dom.nextSibling; // Get the next child node
    }
    // Display the combined values of the child nodes
    document.getElementById('outPut4').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/36NYn/1/) that demonstrates this. In this demo, an `onchange` event handler was added to each select box, which updates the textarea when one of the select boxes change.

Also, the HTML in the demo was edited to improve the formatting of the resulting text in the textarea. Alternatively, the text values could be filtered when traversing the child nodes (removing line breaks and tab characters).

Comment: Thanks Matt. That was a very elegant solution. I will try to apply your js concept to the other parts of my site, as it think it can be adapted easily!

Answer (score 0):

You are already using javascript in the onClick. You need a more complicated bit of it that you call from the onClick that will get the selected text out of the dropdowns and merge it with the other bits.

You will need to duplicate the text content in the html page as you build the text to put into the textarea.